# Apache Pig : Counting frequencies of "character"

Tags: bigdata, apache-pig

Assume there is a text file named abalone_data with 3 attributes : name, gender and length

```
Kn,M,0.89
Un,F,0.77
An,M,0.89
Az,I,0.55
Au,M,0.72
```

with M is male, F is female and I is infant.

The question is how to count the number of abalone of each gender. The desired output should look like this

```
M,3
F,1
I,1
```

I have used the LOAD syntax to load the file, then use the TOKENIZE to get the gender only. But I am stuck at counting the characters.

```
abalone_data = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:9000/pig_data/abalone.data' USING PigStorage(',')
   as (name:chararray, gender:chararray, length:float);
abalone_gender = foreach abalone_data  Generate TOKENIZE(sex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by and Count on the group should be a safe bet? It's a fairly typical operation.

```
abalone_data = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:9000/pig_data/abalone.data' USING PigStorage(',')
   as (name:chararray, gender:chararray, length:float);

gender_counted = FOREACH (GROUP abalone_data BY gender) 
    GENERATE
    group AS gender,
    COUNT(abalone_data) AS gender_count
    ;
```